# Tutorial 'Tasky' does not work

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm a new user and struggling to understand storyboard construction. To help, I went all though tutorial 5 ( 'working with tables & cells') but could not make the segue work  (nothing happens when a cell on the master is clicked). Clearly I have done something wrong , so I searched for some completed source code to see what was missing (the tutorial only has snippets). But the code for the same 'app' on the samples page appears to be totally different, based on an earlier version of Xcode without Storyboards. How frustrating!
To get me on the correct path, has anyone got the complete (working!) code for this tutorial?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The complete code for Tasky can be found on xamarins github repository: https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples

This can also be found through their "Samples" link in the top of the documentation page for iOS: http://samples.xamarin.com/Details/iOS/bd7480f9-cef7-4bba-94cb-1579ae2865b8

Comment: I have already seen this sample, it has the same tite and gives similar results but it uses a .xib not a storyboard. The code structure is totally different so it does not help me see where I have gone wrong in the tutorial which uses a storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking at this tutorial http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Working_with_Tables_and_Cells/Part_5_-_Using_XCode%2c_Interface_Builder%2c_and_Storyboards

The complete samples are downloadable from the first page http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Working_with_Tables_and_Cells
including the Storyboard sample code which is at http://docs.xamarin.com/@api/deki/files/1354/=StoryboardTables.zip

There is also *another* Storyboard sample in the Recipes section that you might find helpful:
http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/recipes/General/Storyboard/Storyboard_a_TableView
(also has complete downloadable source http://docs.xamarin.com/@api/deki/files/1124/=Storyboard_a_Table.zip)

Comment: Thanks Craig. I discovered I hadn't set the table content to 'dynamic prototype'. Earlier this had given me a null cell reference so I created a new cell but this didn't help the segue - the tutorial comment says DequeueReusableCell will 'ALWAYS' return a cell, but it doesn't if they are not dynamic!